# App Engine Flask: enrich Cloud logging entries

Tags: flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I have an App Engine app running on Python with Flask which automatically logs requests to Cloud Logging. I would like to add some info to these log entries. From the client I am passing a new header

`app-version: 1.1.2`

I would like this log to appear for each request. I don't want to create an additional log line but instead extend a log request of this type

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see updated documentation for Python 3, so will assume it's maintaining Python 2 (legacy) behavior.

For GAE Legacy, there are [2 types of log entries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/logs) - Request and Application Logs.

A Request log is automatically written by your App and what you have in your screenshot is a request log.

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice#google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.RequestLog), one of the fields in a Request log is [app_logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice#google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.RequestLog) which are logs emitted by the application while serving the request (i.e. Application Logs which are logs you manually write). So it, looks to me like you can manually log an entry for that header and it'll appear for you under the field `app_logs` in the log entry that you have in your screenshot.

**Update on May 10**

1. Tested with Python 3 and it didn't add the application log entry under the Request Log. It made it a new line entry
2. Tested with Python 2 using `logging.info('my custom log line')`  and it added the application log entry under the request log entry. However, it didn't come under an attribute `app_logs` or `appLogs` as seemed to be implied in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice#google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.RequestLog)

   It appeared as follows

   a) This is the log entry

   [image: Log Header]

   b) When you click on it and it expands, you then get the following at the bottom

[image]

Comment: I added `app.logger.info("my custom log line")` but I don't see it in the log entry in Cloud Logging